# How to filter out identical double requests on server

Tags: django, nginx, request

I've noticed that my Django application from time to time makes double database queries, instead of just one. The log file shows two similar requests at (almost) the exact same time. I know the users are using iPads at locations where the internet connection may be unstable.

Example:

```
[pid: 749|app: 0|req: 892/2837] x.x.x.x () {44 vars in 896 bytes} [Fri Sep  9 12:00:55 2016] GET /clinic_profile/61 => generated 0 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 301) 3 headers in 134 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 750|app: 0|req: 659/2838] x.x.x.x () {44 vars in 898 bytes} [Fri Sep  9 12:00:55 2016] GET /clinic_profile/61/ => generated 84989 bytes in 374 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 3 headers in 102 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

This is a critical flaw in my system. Why is it a critical flaw? For example: A user creates 2 database objects instead of a single one, making a total mess in the database.

**Question:** How can I filter out double requests?

Im using Django, Nginx and Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: So its not possible to reject a request from a user, if time since last request from the user is less than XX?

Comment: Why is this a critical flaw? Can the pages be cached after the first call if you're worried about extra database calls? Your example doesn't really tell of the effects this double call has. I would also question why the first request generated 0 bytes and the second one not so. Should that be happening?

Comment: Ive elaborated why its a critical flaw in the question. 
Yes indeed, if anyone can explain why the first request generated 0 bytes and retuned 301, please do :)

Answer (score 0):

The first URL doesn't have a trailing slash. You are getting a 301 redirect to a url with a trailing slash.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#append-slash